# Getting rid of unwanted characters in a numeric vector

Tags: r

```
                 processor transistor_count     doi          designer   process    area
1        ï»¿Intel 4004            2,300    1971             Intel 10,000 nm 12 mmÂ²
2           Intel 8008            3,500    1972             Intel 10,000 nm 14 mmÂ²
3           Intel 8080            4,500    1974             Intel  6,000 nm 20 mmÂ²
4        Motorola 6800            4,100    1974          Motorola  6,000 nm 16 mmÂ²
5             RCA 1802            5,000    1974               RCA  5,000 nm 27 mmÂ²
6             TMS 1000            8,000 1974[7] Texas Instruments  8,000 nm    <NA>
7  MOS Technology 6502         3,510[8]    1975    MOS Technology  8,000 nm 21 mmÂ²
8           Intel 8085            6,500    1976             Intel  3,000 nm 20 mmÂ²
9            Zilog Z80            8,500    1976             Zilog  4,000 nm 18 mmÂ²
10          Intel 8086           29,000    1978             Intel  3,000 nm 33 mmÂ²
11       Motorola 6809            9,000    1978          Motorola  5,000 nm 21 mmÂ²
12          Intel 8088           29,000    1979             Intel  3,000 nm 33 mmÂ²
13      Motorola 68000           68,000    1979          Motorola  3,500 nm 44 mmÂ²
14           WDC 65C02        11,500[9]    1981               WDC  3,000 nm  6 mmÂ²
```

Hello my friends I am trying to get rid of some characters in the column "`transistor_count`" and "`doi`", as you can see there is these "`[x]`" that prevent me to make that vector a "`numeric`" vector an operate over it. also, I have identifies things like "`~`" and some other characters in that vector. How can you eliminate this "`[8]`" without eliminating an "`8`" from the numbers I want to use. Also, is there a way to check how many of those problematic characters are and what they look like?

I know I can use `gsub` for this and replace the problematic characters that I have spotted that way, but if the data is too big to check one by one? I have tried to use `check.character()` but it didn't even run.

Comment: Perhaps you can fix the problem when you are *reading* the data in. Without knowing the structure of the source file, it is hard to say what this would mean.

Comment: I imported the data through a csv file separated by tabs, then every variable came as a factor and I changed it to character to be able to remove the unwanted characters. Is that what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the columns of interest, use `sub` to match the pattern of `[` followed by one or more digits then a closing bracket `]`, replace it with blank (`""`)

```
df[c("transistor_count", "doi")] <- lapply(df[c("transistor_count", "doi")], 
                 function(x) sub("\\[\\d+\\]", "", x))
```

Comment: Nice one! it looks really good. Do you know what I could use to see if the column more anomalies?